# Pause button doesn't open menu; event issue

Tags: javascript, html, click

I'm implementing an extremely simple pause button and menu into my JavaScript game. When you click the pause button, the menu should appear, and when you click outside of that menu, it should disappear again. Unfortunately, the pause button is located outside the limit of the menu, so when I click the pause button, the menu "appears" but immediately disappears due to the same click event that caused it to open in the first place, since the mouse is outside of the menu.

I'm sure I could solve this problem using super short `setTimeout`'s, or some extra variables, but I feel like there is a more simple solution out there that I've been missing. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="PauseButton" onclick="menu.display(true);"></div>
<div id="Menu"><p>Some text.</p></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    mouseClick(event);
});

var menu = {
    menu: document.getElementById("Menu"),
    pause: document.getElementById("PauseButton"),
    display: function (open) {
        if (open) { // open menu
            this.pause.style.display = "none";
            this.menu.style.display = "block";
        } else { // close menu
            this.pause.style.display = "block";
            this.menu.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function mouseClick(e) {
    if (menu.menu.style.display = "block") {
        if (!menu.menu.contains(e.target)) menu.display(false);
    }
}
```

So it seems that the `onclick` event executes before the event listener executes. I imagine that by swapping this order my problem would be resolved, but I don't know how to do this. Is there a simple solution?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `onclick` and do everything within an event listener attached directly to the pause button, for example:

```
var menu = {
  menu: document.getElementById("Menu"),
  pause: document.getElementById("PauseButton"),
  display: function (open) {
    if (open) {
      // open menu
      this.pause.style.display = "none";
      this.menu.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      // close menu
      this.pause.style.display = "block";
      this.menu.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

menu.pause.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (menu.menu.style.display === "block") {
    menu.display(false)
  } else {
    menu.display(true)
  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, since the menu will only close if you click on the pause button, which is no longer displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Using Brendan C.'s approach, I have solved the problem.

I got rid of the `onclick` in the html, and instead updated the mouseClick function to look like this:

```
function mouseClick(e) {
    if (menu.pause.contains(e.target)) {
        menu.display(true);
    } else if (!menu.menu.contains(e.target)) {
        menu.display(false);
    }
}
```

This works because menu.display will only be called once, no matter what. Thanks again for the tip, Brendan.